# Codeigniter href with new tab

Tags: php, codeigniter

> I am using javascript for showing a link in php Codeigniter. But I want
>   toredirect to a new php page with new tab when click the link . my
>   controller is loginController and my function is downloadPdf().
>   how to do this.

my java script is

```
 contentRow += '<div><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+'loginController/downloadApplication'+' ">click here</a></div>';
```

and this javascript code will append to div in php code

my need is when i click this link ,i have to pass a parameter to the redirecting page for some process.but with codeignitor

Answer (score 1):

use the HTML a `target='_blank'` attribute to link.